# Javascript new window open and print css loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I want to use a new window to print part of HTML.

```
    var cssLink = document.getElementByTagName('link')[2];

    var prtContent = document.getElementById('print_body');

    var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1000,height=auto,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    WinPrint.document.close();

    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
```

But **sometimes** when WinPrint going to do system print, the CSS file still not loaded.

How could I fix it?

Comment: when is this code triggered ? on a click ? or just as it loads the page ? where is this code placed ?

Comment: I think you somehow need to preload the css file or at least listen for a load event in the new window, did you try calling the print method inside a WinPrint.onload function? If that doesn't work then you might need to request the contents of that css file as plain text format, in an ajax call, and inject it right into the DOM of the new window inside of a style tag

Comment: this code run when a print button clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like sometimes the browser isn't loading the CSS file in time for you to print. You can run your printing code only after the css file is loaded, like so:

```
var cssElement = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[2].cloneNode();

var prtContent = document.getElementById('print_body');

var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1000,height=auto,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();

cssElement.addEventListener('load', function () {
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
});

WinPrint.document.head.appendChild(cssElement);
```

Comment: This won't work on Edge. **WinPrint.document.head.appendChild(cssElement)** will cause error

Answer (score 0):

I think it's will work for you.

```
var cssLink = document.getElementByTagName('link')[2];

var prtContent = document.getElementById('print_body');

// open _blank page view before printing
var WinPrint = window.open('','_blank','left=0,top=0,width=1000,height=auto,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

// add new line code here
WinPrint.document.open();
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
WinPrint.document.close();
// remove WinPrint.focus() and WinPrint.print() because it will call print machine of system
```

So if you want to display css for print. You can try.

```
@media print {
    your css here
}
```

View more here: https://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/doc/Printing.html

Comment: I use this method before, but I'm not really sure is that my print_body inside the modal, when I print css didn't work right.